# authorize.net Direct Post hangs at "submitting order information", but takes money from customer

Tags: magento-1.7, authorize.net

For PCI Compliance my client wants to change to Direct Post Method (DPM) for Authorize.net

I originally had an issue with it hanging on "submitting order information" with nothing happening, but I had compilation turned on, turning that off fixed the original issue

my current issue is that it hangs at "submitting order information" but it does process the order, takes the money, and sets the order status properly (pending) in the sites back end

I am getting no related errors in console, I cannot find any JavaScript error to cause this

It may just be taking so much longer than anticipated that we are closing, but we have waited 5+ minutes for this process to complete

### Update

Got the following message posted to the payment page when it finally processed (had one running in the background while making my original post).  Again, the payment was captured successfully and the order in the sites back end was updated correctly

```
error:
An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant. An e-mail  has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card.

This transaction has been approved.
It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you will receive the product or service.
```

### Update 2

Authroize.net has confirmed the problem is a 'time out' while waiting on a response from my Magento site... I send original data to them, they send reply (Magento updates the back end, takes care of all that is necessary to mark order as processed, updates transaction id, etc), but we do not reply to them within 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem is with the Relay Response where the ANET server is unable to POST data.  You can learn more about how to troubleshoot this here: http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Relay-Response-Basics-and-Troubleshooting/ba-p/9536

Comment: But I am getting the transaction id posted to my back end, along with the order itself being moved to `Pending` status.. if I were not receiving the `_POST` data you would think that would not get done?

Comment: Authroize.net has confirmed the problem is a 'time out' while waiting on a response from my Magento site